# Is there a way to send variables from main class to subclass using user input JAVA

Tags: java, string, variables, inheritance, subclass

So I'm working on a (supposedly) simple java application that uses console inputs from a user, to change private variables in another class. Now I can change the value of the private variables in the `EmpCls` class directly from the main class by manually inputting a variable into the object, e.g.
`EmpCls empObject1 = new EmpCls("josh");` but how do I get something like this 
`EmpCls empObject1 = new EmpCls(ctName);` to work? where `ctName` is the variable that the user inputs. here's the relevant code from the main class:

```
import java.util.*;
public class NewWan {
    static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    EmpCls empObject1 = new EmpCls(ctName);
    String ctName = empObject1.getName();

    System.out.println("enter name: ");
    ctName = console.next();

    }
}
```

And the subclass in question:

```
public class EmpCls {

    private String name;
    private String ext;
    private int yearStarted = 0;

    public EmpCls()
    {

    }

    public EmpCls(String inName)
    {

        this.name = inName;

    }

    public void setEmpDetails(String inName) //, String inExt, int inYearStarted)
    {

        this.name = inName;
//          this.ext = inExt;
 //         this.yearStarted = inYearStarted;

    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return this.name;

    }

    public int getYearStarted()
    {
        return this.yearStarted;
    }

    public String getExt()
    {
        return this.ext;
    }

    public void displayDetails()
    {
        System.out.println("Name: " + name);
        System.out.println("Ext: " + ext);
        System.out.println("Year Started" + yearStarted);
    }


}
```

some parts of the code are commented just to enable easier trouble shooting, other parts are part of a different problem im working on.

Comment: call it the same way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hum... just to organize your code in the good way ? You use variable before getting value, and before declare it... Strange way ^^

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("enter name: "); 
    String ctName = console.next();

    EmpCls empObject1 = new EmpCls(ctName);

    System.out.println("You just enter " + empObject1.getName()); 
}
```

Comment: Holy shit, that works. Thanks! Im still a bit of a noob so excuse the strange ordering haha

Comment: No problem, everyone has started one day ^^ Think about using and configure a good IDE for this like, Eclipse, Netbeans or IntelliJ. they are powerfull to show you a large number of error, like this one !

Answer (score 1):

You just need to reorder the statements a bit and remove the one that doesn't make sense:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("enter name: ");
    String ctName = console.next();
    EmpCls empObject1 = new EmpCls(ctName);
}
```